# NHibernate LINQ projection using helper class

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, nhibernate-projections

I'm trying to add projection to an NHibernate LINQ query (via `.select()`), but since I have a bit of logic I want to use a helper class rather than returning a projected model directly.

My code looks like this (shortened):

```
var query = Session.Query<MessageInstance>();
... (a few .Fetch and .ThenFetch calls)
var result = query.Where(specification.IsSatisfiedBy())
                  .OrderBy(m => m.CreationDate)
                  .Select(m => _messageModelHelper.BuildMessageModel(m));
```

`_messageModelHelper` is an object which transforms my `MessageInstance` object into a `MessageModel` and it contains logic to handle different scenarios, since it all depends on related entities.

This fails with error:

> Field Dal.Repositories.MessageRepository._messageModelHelper' is not defined for type 'NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1 [Domain.Entities.Message]'

If I avoid using a field (which is necessary for DI), and do this:

```
.Select(m => new MessageModelHelper().BuildMessageModel(m))
```

I simply get a `System.NotSupportedException`.

It appears my approach won't work. What can I do, while avoiding the need to return `new MessageModel` directly? Also I really need to keep projection, I can't operate on an enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `BuildMessageModel()` "locally":

```
var result = query.Where(specification.IsSatisfiedBy())
                  .OrderBy(m => m.CreationDate)
                  .AsEnumerable() // From this point onward the query
                                  // will be executed C#-side
                  .Select(m => _messageModelHelper.BuildMessageModel(m));
```

Note that, as written, this won't do an SQL projection, so the full object will be selected from the DB.

Comment: Okay, I should have made it more clear but I actually want to keep projection... The reason I can't use `AsEnumerable` anyway is that we have a custom extension method to retrieve a paged collection.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Then first you page, then from the result of paging you do the `_messageModelHelper.BuildMessageModel(m)`, like var result2 = result.Select(m => _messageModelHelper.BuildMessageModel(m)).ToArray();

Comment: @xantos: yes, but there is still no projection then, I want to keep the performance benefits of that.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester What I normally do is project the properties I need and then, with a method, enrich the result object with calculated properties. Clearly the enrichment happens after the query is executed. If I'm lazy I use a single class that is partially filled by the query and partially filled by the enrichment method. If I'm not lazy I create two classes (`PartialResult` and `FinishedResult`), but then I have to copy properties from `PartialResult` to `FinishedResult`.